# How to get residuals as variable in multiple regression in R?

Tags: regression

I am trying to extract regression residuals as a variable to my data so I could use them for different analysis in mydataset.
I use the following code:

```
fresid<-lm(var1 ~ var2+var3+var4+var5, data=female)
```

This gives me a table to the global enviroment, but A am unable to get fitting residuals for my data.

Comment: I assume you have tried `fresid$residuals`, yes?

Comment: `resid(fresid)` or `residuals(fresid)`

Comment: when i try to use command                    
cor(fresid$residuals,female$faceW,use="complete.obs")i get Error in cor : incompatible dimensions

Comment: What are the dimensions of the two? When I try something similar with the R sample datasets it works fine

Comment: using the dim() command i get >null for both.                                   
using > length(female$faceW)
[1] 7955
> length(fresid$residuals)
[1] 7015

Comment: the regression file is not table. if i could copy individual values for regrssion to another file it would work just fine.                                           > dim(fresid)
NULL
> dim(female)
[1] 7955   16